# Different ways to write memcached

Tags: xml, magento, memcached

I'm checking my server config while looking on internet for some tips and I have noticed that `memcached` is writtent in different ways.
I'm referring to this part of `app/etc/local.xml`:

```
<cache>
    <backend>memcached</backend>
...
```

In particular I have seen these ways:

- `memcache` inside `local.xml.additional` and some tutorials
- `memcached` on hosting sites and tutorials
- `Memcached` inside one or two tutorial and stackoverflow answer

My question is: is there any differents? if yes which one is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you referring to this, when saying "in *local.xml.additionnal*"?

```xml
<config>
    <global>
        <session_save><![CDATA[]]></session_save> 
        <!-- db / memcache / empty=files -->
        <!-- ... -->
    </global>
</config>
```

Then you are mistakenly assuming `<session_save>` and `<backend>` under `<cache>` are the same, because later in this same file around line 38 you can read

```xml
<config>
    <global>
        <!-- ... -->
        <cache>
            <backend></backend>
            <!-- apc / memcached / xcache / empty=file -->
        </cache>
        <!-- ... -->
    </global>
</config>
```

So, the answer is, when it comes to `<backend>` ***memcached*** is the right one, when it comes to `<session_save>` ***memcache*** is the right one.

Furthermore, if you refer to `Mage_Core_Model_Cache::_getBackendOptions()` (in */app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php:154*) you can find a big switch statement where `memcached` is one of the case and not `memcache`. Which prove the right value for *cache > backend* is with the final `d`.